# How do you reorganize a dataframe of dataframes so that there's only 1 final dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

If I have a list of df lists, I was wondering how I would go about concatenating all of the dataframes in the nested list and then finally concatenating all of the concatenating all of those dataframes together?
(Looking at the output again, I think this is actually a dataframe of multiple dataframes?)

Here is the input data [the tickers](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gEMXzG7UgzMcVrOEwP0UeumbzviMOkYjmWn7UDKY9E8/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the code I'm using:

```py
#from pandas.io.pytables import DataCol
from six.moves import urllib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jacob/Downloads/CEF Tickers.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

tickers_list = df['Ticker'].tolist()
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=tickers_list)

for ticker in tickers_list:
    data[ticker] = pd.read_html(f'https://www.cefconnect.com/fund/{ticker}', header=0)

export_excel = data.to_excel(r'C:/Users/Jacob/Downloads/ceftest.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index= True)
```

This is the output I get ([link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aRU15ruHLHROiBfjLmwXw_BXVSLB-mzQDG5KDdpbw3I/edit?usp=sharing))

I was hoping to use the tickers as the index and then each column header would be each data point. I also notice that some of the dataframes in the list will not have matching values. For example, the 14th, 15th and 16th dfs will not have matching values to put into the column headers. Would it be possible to make all of them column headers and put "0" in the cell? Or how do you think I should deal with those dfs? Drop them out completely? If so, how would I removed those final 3 frames in the process of concatenating everything?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I merge a dataframe of many dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068520/how-would-i-merge-a-dataframe-of-many-dataframes)

Comment: I'm not sure how to merge dataframes that are within a dataframe. In order to get the individual dfs before merging into 1 big df, I tried creating 16 different merges based on their loc(N,)  but the output is an empty dataframe.